# how to compare two endpoint address with C++ in windows:

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, networking, winsock

`bool checkSockaddr(sockaddr_in a, sockaddr_in b)`

check if they two have the same address information.

Comment: c'mon, there's a question in there somewhere wanting to be asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bool checkSockaddr(sockaddr_in const &a, sockaddr_in const &b) { 
        return a.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr == b.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr;
    }